# What does "wild west mentality" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does the phrase in bold mean "it makes us think about the primitive age of mid-19th century capitalism"?

> There are a couple of things that could kill the hype for the digital currency and help push demand in the opposite direction. One of them is a Lehman or Enron-style fraud event, not necessarily in the Bitcoin market, but in some other cryptocurrency market, which brings to mind the **wild west mentality** of mid-19th century capitalism.

<sub>Source: [Forbes magazine](https://www.forbes.com/sites/panosmourdoukoutas/2017/12/04/two-events-that-could-send-bitcoin-back-towards-1k/#3473510a579c)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Wild West](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wild-west?q=wild%20west) refers to the western part of the US during the mid-19th century. It was an era characterised by violence (particularly between the incoming Europeans and the Native Americans) and anarchy.

So, the "wild west mentality" of 19th-century capitalism invokes the idea that in those days, capitalism was more disorganised, chaotic and possibly even violent.

Comment: +1 although we should note that the "violence and anarchy" exists mainly in popular culture and fiction, more than it ever did in real life.